# Create custom markdown-blocks from R code

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Is it possible to create a [custom markdown block](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html) within a R function?

Background: I have a custom function which renders a table in a very custom format. At the end of the table I would love to append a standardized text, such as "Table 1: title of my amazing table" in the format `my-format`. `my-format` refers to a custom style from a reference_docx. It generates a word document. So in markdown I would write:

````
```{r}
ft <- flextable(...)
ft # print out flextable
```

:::{custom-style="my-format"}
Table 1: title of my amazing table
:::
````

Instead I would like to write:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
ft
cat(paste(':::{custom-style="my-format"}',
    'Table 1: title of my amazing table',
    ':::', '', sep="\n"))
```
````

However, it does not work as intended. It does not print my flextable anymore. Since this code is inside a function I can't make two `r` blocks out of it.

Comment: Couldn't you print the markdown table caption outside of the code block and then modify the style `my-format` so that the caption appeared just below the table (e.g., by removing space between lines in the Word style)?